# Change elements of page with .on change event in an elegant way

Tags: javascript, d3.js

for my thesis I wrote some JavaScript code using the d3.js library to create dynamic data visualizations based on a database. I have some elements that allow the user to apply some changes to the visualizations, and the diagrams react accordingly. And here's my question: since I learned alla that myself, I used to copy and paste the parts of code that I needed for the updates in the .on change event listeners, making the code really long (and redundant I think). Is there a more elegant way to solve this, shortening the code and making it easier to debug, read, and just to make it look better? The code is structured so I have many variables that are linked to each other, because many stuff is related. One example of the code:

```
//The two histogram variables
var histogSans = d3 .layout.histogram()
                    .bins(bin)
                    .value(function (d) { return d[SelX]; })
                    (FontSans);
var histogSerif = d3.layout.histogram()
                    .bins(bin)
                    .value(function (d) { return d[SelX]; })
                    (FontSerif);

//Max values of the two histograms
var MaxSans = d3.max(histogSans, function (d) { return d.y; });
var MaxSerif = d3.max(histogSerif, function (d) { return d.y; });
```

And then on an .on("change") event I need to update those values, so I just pasted the whole code again -and this happens also if some elements of the visualizations need to be updated (svg elements mostly).
Is there a way I can avoid this? I know it's a pretty basic question, but my knowledge in JavaScript is not that great.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a straightforward [Extract Method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) refactoring.

```
var histogSans  = hist(FontSans);
var histogSerif = hist(FontSerif);

function hist(fontName) {
    return d3 .layout.histogram()
              .bins(bin)
              .value(function (d) { return d[SelX]; })
              (fontName);
}
```

Does that meet your needs?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. And in the onchange event listener can I just paste: histogSans  = hist(FontSans);
histogSerif = hist(FontSerif); to avoid redundancy?